# Pathauto, flags and contextual filter not working

Tags: views, flags, path-aliases

I have a content type called ev and a flag for this content type.

I want a view that displays the users that flagged content.

When I build the user view with a relatioship  **Flags: User's flaggings (bookmarks)** and **(user flagged content) Flags: Entity ID** it works but only when the path is **node/%/at**

If the path is **content/%/at** it does not work nor it adds the menu item. Why is that happening?

Comment: Even when I give a fixed value of a node, the view content/%/at does not work, it shows no results. The preview however works.

Comment: If you provide default, content id from url, what happens?

Comment: Nothing still. I figured it out. So views cannot have path auto urls (at least not with contextual filters). Instead I installed sub pathauto and then used the path node/%/at. Subpathauto translated the url so that it would work with its aliased form. The contextual filter required validation criteria also.